# A pattern to remove 'minus' characters with some commas between them

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I'm looking for a pattern for SED (preferred) or other utility that can process regexp's to remove unnecessary `-` and `,` characters from a file.txt.

I want to remove everything that looks like this:

```
-----------,-------------------------------------,---------,-,---------,---------
```

WITHOUT deleting ANY commas that are not near a minus, and WITHOUT removing any minuses if they are followed by numbers or letters.

The pattern I'm looking for is `-,` and `,-` and `--` (I think so)

Comas and minuses that aren't matching the pattern should be left untouched ;)

The input looks like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,xxxx
------------------,------------------,----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------,-,---,---------------------------,-----------------,---------
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxxöxxx,xxx,1103469,27-xxx-76,x,01-xxx-99,31-xxx-01,,273,321,321,2
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxx,xxxxx,1103759,13-xxx-61,x,01-xxx-99,30-xxx-01,,~,321,321,1
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxxxxx,xxxx,1109909,01-xxx-70,x,01-xxx-99,31-xxx-00,,~,321,321,1
```

The desired output:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,xxxx
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxxöxxx,xxx,1103469,27-xxx-76,x,01-xxx-99,31-xxx-01,,273,321,321,2
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxx,xxxxx,1103759,13-xxx-61,x,01-xxx-99,30-xxx-01,,~,321,321,1
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxxxxx,xxxx,1109909,01-xxx-70,x,01-xxx-99,31-xxx-00,,~,321,321,1
```

Comment: @fedorqui - everything else in the file (it's a CSV data file) should be left untouched. I only need to remove the unnecessary -----,----,-- characters. They come in a pattern - at least two minuses, a minus followed by a coma, or a coma followed by a minus.

Comment: @dziki give an example.

Comment: @fedorqui - I've updated the question with input and desirable output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -i.bak -r '/(-+,)+-+$/d' input
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,xxxx
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxxöxxx,xxx,1103469,27-xxx-76,x,01-xxx-99,31-xxx-01,,273,321,321,2
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxx,xxxxx,1103759,13-xxx-61,x,01-xxx-99,30-xxx-01,,~,321,321,1
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxxxxx,xxxx,1109909,01-xxx-70,x,01-xxx-99,31-xxx-00,,~,321,321,1
```

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F '(-+,)+-+$' '$NF' input
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,xxxx
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxxöxxx,xxx,1103469,27-xxx-76,x,01-xxx-99,31-xxx-01,,273,321,321,2
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxx,xxxxx,1103759,13-xxx-61,x,01-xxx-99,30-xxx-01,,~,321,321,1
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxxxxx,xxxx,1109909,01-xxx-70,x,01-xxx-99,31-xxx-00,,~,321,321,1
```

Or even this awk works:

```
awk -F '(-+,)+-+$' 'NF==1' input
```

Comment: The last one worked like a charm, Havent even seen that You posted another two :) Thanks, Worked perfectly!

Comment: @dziki: You're welcome, other 2 commands also work, just in case you want to try them :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$ sed 's/--\+\|-,\+\|,-//g; /^$/d' input
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,xxxx
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxxöxxx,xxx,1103469,27-xxx-76,x,01-xxx-99,31-xxx-01,,273,321,321,2
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxx,xxxxx,1103759,13-xxx-61,x,01-xxx-99,30-xxx-01,,~,321,321,1
1999,2014,591025,xöxxxxxxx,~,~,xxxxxxx,xxxx,1109909,01-xxx-70,x,01-xxx-99,31-xxx-00,,~,321,321,1
```

Or a much good looking sed using `-r` option

```
$ sed -r 's/--+|-,+|,-//g; /^$/d' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Another sed option

```
sed '/^[-,]\+$/d'  file
```

Another awk

```
awk '!/^[-,]+$/' file
```

Those will work for your output